# Refactoring a Function for Efficiency and Legibility

Tags: javascript, refactoring

I need to rewrite the body of the function to make a single return statement and declare no variables.

```
function labyrinth(x, y) {
  var x = 4 * x * y;
  var y = 3 * y + 5;
  var z = x + y;
  return z;
}
```

First attempt

```
function labyrinth(x, y) {
  return ((4xy) + (3y + 5));
}
```

Comment: `4xy`? You mean `4 * x * y` (same with `3y` should be `3 * y`).

Comment: "*make a single return statement and declare no variables*" - that will neither help with legibility nor with efficiency of the function.

Comment: Thank you to all who helped. This is an exercise on an assignment. Very helpful input from everyone.